# Testing with Mocha/Chai and struggling to write functional before(function)

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js, chai

I am a noob to both Node and mocha/chai.  I'm attempting to write tests for a node script I wrote.  I have written the following before function:

```
before(function (done) {
    dive(testInc, function (err, file) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            incData.push(data);
            console.log(incData.length);  // shows length as array is built
        });
        incFiles.push(file);
    }, function () {
        console.log("incFiles populated");
        done(); // Wrong place to call done? 
    });
```

Inside of the `fs.readFile` callback I can see the `incData` array is correctly created.  However, I don't seem to have access to this array outside of `before`.  I know it has to do with async and I've tried adding `done` to the function parameters but I'm still not getting it right.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `before`-function is asynchronous, so you need to specify a callback method. Otherwise mocha will start your tests before everything in the `before`-function will be ready.

```
before(function(done){
  //call done, if everything is ready
  done()
})
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  I modified the code to show what I was trying with `done` that still isn't working for me.